# How to copy data from an Hive table to a HBase table which is already loaded with some data

Tags: hive, hbase, sqoop

We have an Hive table which is partitioned on date (yyyy-MM-dd), and this table is daily loaded with new data for latest date partition. And also this table has last 2 years of data(partitioned).

Now we are migrating the system in to HBase, we want to copy the data from Hive table, partition by partition to HBase. There is an another process which loads the data into HBase table with new data on daily basis(like date parition in hive). We designed row key as combination of bucket (pkid%16),schema(few bytes of md5), date(string to byte array), pkid(long to byte array) values.

We want to copy data from Hive to HBase, is there any better way for achieving this and the solution should not give any impact on the data which we are bringing on daily basis (sqooping from oracle db to HBase).

Comment: please do let me know your suggestions or ideas on this...